# Why are HTML article, aside tags required when we are able to create our own tags?

Tags: css, html

If I write HTML as below, still I can access tag called 'veera' in CSS, JS. Why we should use only article, header, nav, etc. when we can write whatever tags we want?

```css
  veera{
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
  }
  h3{
  color: yellow;
  }
veera h3{
color: green;
}
```

```html
  <veera>
  <h3>hello world</h3>
  <p>this a paragraph and outstanding extra text to show some thing huge text lines csused data load or some othr thoughts </p>
  </veera>
```

Comment: **SeMAnTic WeB**

Comment: and why writing anything when we can write CLEAR and well named things ? it doesn't make sense ... h1 is a title, everyone know it's a title so when you use it we know it's a title ... but what is veera ? no meaning ... So some clever people deciced to create some useful tags to help the world and to give meaning to code

Comment: `Why we should use only ` --> and no one is forcing you to use only them, you are free to use what you want but again : why ?

Answer (score 0):

In General web scenario **HTML** is used to present the user interface... so it's standard tag also tell you which type of content you have to put in which **tag**.
like **nav**, **header**, **address**, **footer** etc...

Another thing is this is the standard way. if you create your custom tag other person don't understand your custom tag you have developed. it is also not considered as your standrad html website in **HTML Checker**. and also so some browser behave anonymously on your custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is all about structure and semantics. `<veera>` is not semantic, like `<b>` for a bold text is also not semantic. It has no meaning. For a bold text you should use `<strong>` because it's describing that the text within is strong and so it is important. Most of the time browsers will make `strong` text bold, but hey, if you want a text to be bold you should use CSS, because CSS is for styling while HTML is not.

So main point, It's just not semantic and not how you suppose to write html. You can find more over this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).

Comment: Thanks for explanation Gijsberts,   I understand, those html tags are recommended not mandatory to use. but nowhere mention this. you may use own defined tags which is not good practice. and also one more point. If i want to use some meaningful name like opened, ordered, prepared-list etc, its good idea. isn't it??